# Svelte 3: Event Handling not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, event-handling, svelte-3

On Svelte 3.12.1, when event handler **onFilesChange** is triggered, it unexpectedly triggers **onFileClick**.

```
<script>
  let files = [];
  function previewImage(file) {
    return "<img src='" + file.previewURL + "' />";
  }
  function onFileClick(file) {
    console.log("onFileClick");
    files.splice(files.findIndex(x => x.name === file.name), 1);
    files = files;
  }
  function onFilesChange(event) {
    console.log("onFilesChange");
    let inputFiles = event.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++)
      files.push({inputFile: inputFiles.item(i), previewURL: URL.createObjectURL(inputFiles.item(i))});
    files = files;
  }
</script>

<input accept="image/*" multiple name="files" type="file" on:change={onFilesChange}/>
{#each files as file}
  <figure on:click={onFileClick(file)}>
    {@html previewImage(file)}
  </figure>
{/each}
```

But if I slightly change to using arrow functions, then it works as expected. Why is this happening, and what is the proper way to handle DOM events in Svelte 3?

```
<input accept="image/*" multiple name="files" type="file" on:change={(event) => onFilesChange(event)}/>
{#each files as file}
  <figure on:click={(file) => onFileClick(file)}>
    {@html previewImage(file)}
  </figure>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `on:whatever` event handler values need to be functions that will be called with the DOM event as an argument. `on:change={onFilesChange}` is fine because `onFilesChange` is a function which expects an event as its argument. `on:click={onFileClick(file)}` is not because that will call `onFileClick(file)` right away, and the return value from *that* is expected to be an event handler.

You should use `on:click={() => onFileClick(file)}` so that the event handler is a function, which will be passed the DOM event (which gets discarded) and then calls `onFileClick(file)`.